# python: search for a 5 digit number instead of specific number

Tags: python, regex, numbers, digit

Instead of trying to search for `150,00`, `200,00`, `250,00` `300,00` or `1.000,00`, `1.100,00` is it possible to compare strings against for example `xxx,xx €` and `x.xxx,xx €` regardless of the numbers?

The code that I've gotten from eLRuL works fine, but it's also giving me the format xx,xx. I only want xxx,xx and x.xxx,xx and I would like also to include the euro sign at the end so it should include this xxx,xx € and x.xxx,xx € .

```html
if re.search(r'\d+\.?\d+,?\d+', item['Value']):
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a way and you have tagged it: "regex" (regular expressions). In Python you can use either [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module or [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module.

First you have to create the pattern, in your case:

```
import re

number = str(<what_you_want_to_search>) #for example 1,000.00 or 100.00
pat = r'(\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2}' #pattern for xxx.xx and x,xxx.xx numbers
result = re.search(pat, number)
if result:
    print result.string
```

re.search returns None if there's no match of the expression and an object if there is. Then you can print out what was the string that matches with the pattern.

I strongly recommend you to read the documentation of the package to know  exactly how to create your own regex.

Edit:

As you say, the pattern r'\d+.?\d+,?\d+' is working but is matching with xx,xx too. You have to be more specific:

pat = r'(\d,)?\d{3}.\d{2}'

That pattern matches

1. Numbers with comma at start after the first digit, but optionally
   because the ? symbol. i.e: x,...
2. Then there's exactly 3 numbers and a decimal symbol (.)
3. Last but not least, exactly 2 numbers.

So this pattern matches with x,xxx.xx or xxx.xx expressions as you wanted at first.

Then if you want to match with the Euro symbol(€) you have to [add](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm) the characters from Sc manually to your pattern.

Comment: so (\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2} is the paterrn for xxx.xx and x,xxx.xx numbers ? I only want to search for that pattern,. But how do i implement this in my python code ? Since in my original code, I also have the url saved where that number was found. I will update my question with the whole code.  Do i need to combine this with the response.url in the code i posted above ?

Comment: What's in item['stake'] ? The whole bunch of numbers?

Comment: @ user3926962 if item['Stake'] in [u'50,00\x80', u'100,00\x80']: - Yes, those are the numbers that i look for, i just shortened it, because i have more numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to implement this ? I've used eLRuLL suggestion and just replaced if item [Stake] and it's working. However, it's also returning xx,xx . I only wanted xxx,xx and x.xxx,xx and with the Euro sign at the end so like this. xxx,xx €

Comment: Ok, no problem. I think that's because that's the wrong pattern for what you are looking for.

Comment: I've also tried your pattern like this if re.search(r'\d,)?\d{3}\.\d', item['Stake']): , but I'm getting an error.

Comment: What's the error? item['stake'] has just one value or a list of values?, post what are you trying if you want. It's easier to help you if we can se the code or the error messages

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-win32.egg\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\FinalSpider\FinalSpider\spiders\final_spider.py", line 21, in parse
    if re.search(r'\d,)?\d{3}\.\d', item['Stake']):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unbalanced parenthesis

Comment: item['URL'] = response.url
        item['Stake'] = ''.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="ccc"]//span[@class="ccc" or @class="currency"]/text()').extract())
        if re.search(r'\d,)?\d{3}\.\d', item['Stake']):
            return item

Comment: The pattern (r'\d,)?\d{3}\.\d' is wrong. This: r'(\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2}' is good. What you used as the pattern wasn't a valid string, replace it with the valid one.

Comment: Ok. I've tried that, but it's not giving back any results.

Comment: item['Stake'] has to be a string of a number (valid or invalid, but a number). I don't know if you can pass a list as parameter for search() method

Comment: Not sure how to do that, so I've edited my question. Thanks for your thoughtful input.

Comment: You're welcome! print out item['Stake'] ... maybe I can help you.

Comment: Do you mean to add print item ['Stake'] instead of return item ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `regex`:

```
import re
...

if re.search(r'\d+\.?\d+,?\d+', item['Value']):
```

Comment: I've added that, but it's also returning numbers like 10,00 . I only wanted 100,00 and 1,000.00 format. I forgot to add, is it possible to add the Euro sign at the end ? So xxx,xx € so it doesn't return other currencies ? Like \d+\.?\d+,?\d+ \x80 ?